Erreur : An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Some
In my project I have members who each have different galleries. I'm looking to make a method that allows me to have all the showrooms associated with my member. I have a OneToMany relationship between member and showroom. I don't understand the error that is returned, it's like my member entity did not want there to be the id of a member in the route of a showroom method. I put dumps in my code which gives me the information I want so I don't see where it's blocking. Can you help me please? I'm on Symfony4
ShowroomController
 #[Route('/membre/{id}/showroom', name: 'app_showroom_index', methods: ['GET'])]
    public function index(int $id, MembreRepository $membreRepository): Response
    {
        // Récupérer le membre via son ID
        $membre = $membreRepository->find($id);
        
        if (!$membre) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Membre introuvable.');
        }
        
        // Afficher l'ID du membre avec dump()
        dump($membre->getId());  // ou dump($id) pour afficher directement l'ID reçu dans l'argument
        
        // Récupérer les showrooms associés au membre via la relation
        $showrooms = $membre->getShowrooms();
        dump($showrooms->first());
        
        return $this->render('showroom/index.html.twig', [
            'showrooms' => $showrooms,
        ]);
    }

MembreController :
class MembreController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/membre', name: 'app_membre_index', methods: ['GET'])]
    public function index(MembreRepository $membreRepository): Response
    {
        $membres = $membreRepository->findAll();
        
        return $this->render('membre/index.html.twig', [
            'membres' => $membres,
        ]);
    }
    

Twig membre/index :
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}
Liste des membres
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<h1>Liste des membres</h1>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>email</th>
            <th>roles</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for membre in membres %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ membre.id }}</td>
            <td>{{ membre.email }}</td>
            {% for role in membre.roles %}
            <td>{{ role }}</td>
            <td><a href="{{ path('app_membre_show', {'id' : membre.id}) }}">
                    Voir la fiche du membre </a></td>
                    {{ dump(membre.id) }}
                    {{ dump('test') }}  {# Vérifiez si 'test' s'affiche dans la barre de débogage #}
                    
<td><a href="{{ path('app_showroom_index', {'membre_id': membre.id}) }}">Voir les showrooms</a></td>

            {% endfor %}
            </td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}

    </tbody>
</table>

{% endblock %}

twig showroom/index :
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Showroom index{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <h1>Showroom index</h1>

    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Publiee</th>
                <th>actions</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {% for showroom in showrooms %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ showroom.id }}</td>
                <td>{{ showroom.description }}</td>
                <td>{{ showroom.publiee ? 'Yes' : 'No' }}</td>
                <td>
                    <a href="{{ path('app_showroom_show', {'id': showroom.id}) }}">show</a>
                    <a href="{{ path('app_showroom_edit', {'id': showroom.id}) }}">edit</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        {% else %}
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4">no records found</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <a href="{{ path('app_showroom_new') }}">Create new</a>
{% endblock %}

I tried to remove the dependency of the member id in the showroom index route but without success.

"I don't understand the error that is returned" - Please [edit] the question and add the full error, as text, inside of it.

This line
{{ path('app_showroom_index', {'membre_id': membre.id}) }}

should be
{{ path('app_showroom_index', {'id': membre.id}) }}

because
#[Route('/membre/{id}/showroom', name: 'app_showroom_index', methods: ['GET'])]

expects the variable to be named id (not membre_id)

If this is the case, then you should place this as a comment and close-vote as non-reproducible or typo - Furthermore, as OP didn't even provide the actual error, how are you sure this will solve the issue(s)?
